# How can I select the IP address from the output of the `ip route` command?

Tags: linux, sed, grep, pattern-matching

> $ ip route get 255.255.255.255
>
> broadcast 255.255.255.255 dev eth0 src 192.168.223.129

I want to get the IP address of `192.168.223.129` all I know is that I have to use the `sed` command. Also, can you please describe the command used?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: i was trying something related to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223508/selecting-part-of-text-from-output-of-another-command

Comment: Is it ok if you can do it without `sed` or is there a requirement that you must use `sed`? (Homework etc.)

Comment: should be available by default in linux :)

Comment: No i meant is it ok if you use another tool? I have posted an answer, see if that meets your requirements, else i'll delete it.

Comment: AWK is a better tool for splitting fields than sed. You might also consider Perl or Ruby for field-splitting.

Comment: @axiom your answer absolutely works but i will have to accept the better among the correct ones :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a pattern matching problem which `grep` is simplest and most suited tool to do this.

What you are looking to match is an IP address following the word `src`. You can you use this regex to match an IP address: `(\d{1,3}.){4}` and use [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure the IP address follows the word `src` like `(?<=src )`:

```
$ ip route get 255.255.255.255 | grep -Po '(?<=src )(\d{1,3}.){4}'
192.168.223.129
```

To use positive lookahead with `grep` you need to use the `-P` flag for perl regular expressions and the `-o` flag tells `grep` to only display the matching part of the line as the default behaviour of `grep` is to display the whole line that contains a match.

This solution is independent of the output from `ip route get 255.255.255.255` as you are searching for and IP address following the word `src` and not relying on the format of the output such as it happening to be the last word on the first line.

Comment: This answer depends on having grep compiled with PCRE, which is not always going to be the case. If you haven't compiled in PCRE, or have access to pcregrep, then this answer will not work. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

if I would extract text, the first thing comes up is grep/ack.

try this:

```
ip route get 255.255.255.255|grep -oP '(?<=src ).*'
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Use AWK Instead

This problem is easier to solve with AWK. Assuming it's not a homework assignment, use the right tool for the job! For example, to store the IP address in a variable for later use, you can do the following:

```
ip_address=$(
    ip route get 255.255.255.255 |
    awk '{print $NF; exit}'
)
```

You can then access the value through the your new variable. For example:

```
$ echo "$ip_address"
192.168.1.1
```

Comment: @sudo_O Up to you. AWK intrinsically handles field-splitting; if you want to split the fields yourself using some other tool, go right ahead.

Comment: I don't consider this a field splitting problem at all, it's just so happens that it's the last word on the first line in this case but what the OP wants is just the source IP so imo it would be better to teach how to do that. Yes `awk` would be a great choice to get that last field but that's not the really the problem. A little bit more explanation also might be nice.

Comment: The result I got of the command `ip route get 255.255.255.255` is like this. So I can't get the actual IP.
broadcast 255.255.255.255 dev eth0 src 173.82.1.1 uid 1000 
    cache <local,brd>

Answer (score 1):

If you can do with out `sed`, here is something that will work : 
Output of `ip route`

```
[aman@aman ~]$ ip route get 255.255.255.255
broadcast 255.255.255.255 dev wlan0  src 192.168.1.4 
    cache <local,brd>
```

Getting the `ip` address

```
[aman@aman ~]$ ip route get 255.255.255.255|head -1|cut -f7 -d' '
192.168.1.4
```

Comment: sure. `head -1` picks out the first line, `cut` gets me field number 7, where the fields are separated by single spaces (there is a double space after wlan0 so it counts as 1 field). for more info, type in `man cut` and `man head`.

Answer (score 1):

With sed you could do it like this:

```
ip route get 255.255.255.255 | sed -n '/src/ s/.*src //p'
```

`-n` suppresses output. The `/src/` bit selects which lines to perform the substitute `s///` and print `p` command on. The substitute command `s/.*src //` removes everything up to and including `src` (notice the trailing space).